# Javascript - Cannot display more than 4 days of the week?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to show a schedule that lists the remaining days of the week, but it doesn't work if i use getDay() more than 4 times in the function, which is necessary for getting the days. I made a small sample code to show what i mean. Uncomment the line and it should not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("hit");
    var d = new Date();
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";

    var a = weekday[d.getDay()];
    var b = weekday[(d.getDay() + 1) % 7];
    var c = weekday[(d.getDay() + 2) % 7];
    var d = weekday[(d.getDay() + 3) % 7];
    //var e = weekday[(d.getDay() + 4) % 7];

    document.getElementById("day1").innerHTML = a;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<h1 id="day1">Test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can solve this with pure JavaScript but in my opinion the date are more  complex that what the developers think.. and It get even worst it you try to do it with poor native js way.. I recommend you use [http://momentjs.com/](moment.js) It's an abstraction to all the complicate things going on with dates that we don't have on mind..

Answer (score 1):

You reassign the variable `d`.

```
var d = weekday[(d.getDay() + 3) % 7];
```

However, it seems unnecessary to solve this problem when you can just call d.getDay() one time, store that in a variable and then do your other manipulations from that.  Eg:

```
function myFunction() {
    alert("hit");
    var d = new Date();
    var day = d.getDay(); 

    var weekday = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

    var a = weekday[day];
    var b = weekday[(day + 1) % 7];
    var c = weekday[(day + 2) % 7];
    var d = weekday[(day + 3) % 7];
    var e = weekday[(day + 4) % 7];

    document.getElementById("day1").innerHTML = a;
}
```

Comment: Works when I use that thanks. I'm getting a lot of weird problems with js, could that be due to memory? Stuff like html lines showing if there are duplicate lines below it, but not working if its just one line.

Comment: No, that should not happen.  Post a new question with details